# jQuery - Get the first image from parsed xml feed (content:encoded)

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing

I am able to search through an XML feed with the following code

```
$($xml).find('item').each(function(i, e) { ... }
```

For each item within this loop, I am able to access my content:encoded element with the following lines and see the results...

```
    $mcontent = $(this).find('encoded').text();
    console.log('source: ' + $mcontent.match(/<img[^>]*>/g));
```

...which contains multiple images separated by commas like this...

```
<p><img src="...">, <img src="...">, <img src="..."></p>
```

How can I get the first image element only, and store than into an $mImage variable?

Thanks!

**Update:**

When I try to do the following...

```
    $mcontent = $(this).find('encoded').text();
    $mcontent = $mcontent.match(/<img[^>]*>/g).split(',')[0];
    console.log('source: ' + $mcontent);
```

The browser tells me that...

```
Uncaught TypeError: $mcontent.match(...).split is not a function
```

..and I don't know why...

Comment: "your-image,string, here".split(',')[0] would give you the first image as a string.

Comment: I have one more question above, in trying to implement this...I also forgot an element from my original issue...

Comment: Thanks axel for the reminder on split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your text is:

```
<p><img src="...">, <img src="...">, <img src="..."></p>
```

you may use:

```
var str = '<p><img src="...">, <img src="...">, <img src="..."></p>';
var firstImg = $($.parseHTML(str)[0]).find('img:first');
```

> Uncaught TypeError: $mcontent.match(...).split is not a function

This happens because *"$mcontent.match(/]*>/g)"* returns an array of img and it's enough you get the first ele:

The snippet:

```js
var str = '<p><img src="...">, <img src="...">, <img src="..."></p>';
var firstImg = $($.parseHTML(str)[0]).find('img:first');

console.log(firstImg[0].outerHTML);



var t = str.match(/<img[^>]*>/g)[0];

console.log(t);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```